# count the numbers of words only from string in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string, list, count

```py
txt = "The rain in Spain3 3545 & %"

count = len(re.findall(r'\w+', txt))

print (count)
```

output=5

The desired output was 3 . Words "The" ,"rain","in" these only need to be counted.
program didnt count the special characters but counting numbers.How can remove the numbers also and count words only

Comment: What is your desired result? Should `Spain3` be counted? What about a word like `2nd`? What about a word like `isn't`?

Comment: How many actual "words" should be counted from your sample input?

Comment: The desired output is 3 .The words with numbers or special characters also need to be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try counting the number of terms which match `\b[A-Za-z]+\b`:

```py
txt = "The rain in Spain3 3545 & %"
matches = re.findall(r'\b[A-Za-z]+\b', txt)
print(len(matches))  # 3
```

If on the other hand you want to define a word as being any number of alphanumeric characters so long as at least one letter be present, then you can use the above approach with the pattern `\b\w*[A-Za-z]\w*\b`:

```py
txt = "The rain in Spain3 3545 & %"
matches = re.findall(r'\b\w*[A-Za-z]\w*\b', txt)
print(len(matches))  # 4
```